# Why can't a tag be deleted from the question if the question has no other tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

Consider [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/13493/105), which I voted to close as OT.

Given that there might not be enough close votes, I also wanted to delete the only tag that is there, as being inappropriate for the question.

It is possible to pose a question without assigning any tags. Why is it not possible to delete an inappropriate tag if it is the only one present?

Comment: They usually assign an *untagged*, but that's only in very young betas, iirc.

Comment: @M.A.Ramezani: Sorry, I don't understand. Do you mean assign a tag whose name is `untagged`? Yes, I suppose I could do that, but why? I still do not understand the reason for the rule that you cannot delete the last tag.

Comment: @M.A.Ramezani You can't manually assign "untagged". The "untagged" tag is only applied to those questions for which all existing tags have been deleted by an automatic process (like the ones described in Shog's answer).

Comment: Oh, that's good to know @senshin. Thanks for the info. But yeah . . . Shog's right. Even when one user suggests and edit, a bad tag might be introduced, but if it's edited out, it won't live for long.

Comment: Well, the question has now been edited by @nicael to render it meaningless. The question was based on the mistaken assumption (stated in the original question) that you could post a question without any tags. I will delete the question, now that it has been edited to remove that assumption, as it makes no sense now.

Comment: Okay, rolled back.  But it doesn't really matter. The question is a valid one even without that sentence.

Comment: @nicael: Thank you. At least the question is coherent now, if mistaken. I think it should just be deleted, as it and the answers are more likely to confuse than to help. But as you say, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: I've edited my comment. You can't delete it by the way.

Answer (score 4):

Because a question must have at least one topic which is in the scope of this site.

If you can't pick any tag for that question, it's off-topic, therefore it shouldn't really exist, so it must get deleted soon. It's not worth editing a question which is definitely off-topic.

Comment: Then why allow questions to be created with no tag? Why allow edits that do not add a tag to a tagless question? Either every question requires a tag or not. Why enforce this only for the operation of tag deletion?

Comment: @Drew there's no such questions and one can't post a question without tags.

Comment: My bad. I didn't realize that. In that case, I withdraw my question. Thx. [Update: Well, I was going to delete the question, but changed my mind when I saw the message admonishing against that.]

Comment: Not 100% true. For example when there is a new movie,  question about that new movie is on topic on http://movies.stackexchange.com/ and there's no generic tag for that, meaning new tag must be created first. If user without enough rep is the first to ask, he's "stuck" and must either ask on the meta site or wait for someone else to create the tag.

Comment: @Sha "question about that new movie" - what a question, exactly? Look at [some of the top tags there](http://movies.stackexchange.com/tags). There's no need to have a question tagged with a movie name - one must pick a more general topic first.

Answer (score 0):

Once the question itself is deleted, the tag will also be deleted within 24 hours.

Even if for some reason the question *isn't* deleted, the tag will be removed after 6 months if it isn't used anywhere else and if no one bothers to write a tag wiki for it.

If you want it gone sooner, replace it with a more appropriate tag.

Comment: @Shog9: But if the question is not deleted and the tag is a commonly used tag, then it remains, inappropriately. Whether a question should be closed is not related to whether a tag is appropriate. And just because a given tag is inappropriate, it does not follow that some other tag is appropriate (except perhaps a meta-tag of the sort `untagged`). Why require replacement instead of allowing deletion of an inappropriate tag?

Comment: You've misunderstood the question. OP is asking why can't a tag be removed from the question if it is the only one.

Comment: If the question is on-topic, there **must** be an appropriate tag, @drew. If one does not already exist, then create a new one. If it is off-topic, then it should be deleted - at that point, the tagging doesn't matter.